# Create a readable report (PDF) from XML output in Java

Tags: java, xml, pdf, report, output

I'm trying to make a tool that's able to import XML output files from a certain tool and 'convert' them into nice a nice PDF report that sums things up in understandable language for normal people.

Output files always contain specific data, but I just want my appliciation to automatically create a report that's not hard to read for someone who's not very familiar with technology.

I know it's impossible to do completely automated, so I guess I'll have to use some kind of pre-defined templates or something, but I'm not sure what the best solution is.

Importing and reading the XML files isn't hard, but how do I convert them to a readable PDF document?

Comment: Your question isn't very specific, so I'm not sure how to answer it but check out iText and maybe take a look at this link for some ideas.(http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/06/26/generating-pdfs-with-flying-saucer-and-itext.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) may help. This is a print formatter. Uses [XSL-FO](http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/xslfo_intro.asp) (XSL Formatting Objects) as template, and supports pdf as output. XSL-FO is a language for formatting XML data.